# Why a new migration on making a property virtual?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I had entities such as this:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
    public Bar2 Bar2 { get; set; }
}

public class Bar 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class Bar2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

which migrations are:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Bar",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Description = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.Bar2",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Description = c.String(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.Foo",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Bar_Id = c.Int(),
            Bar2_Id = c.Int(),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Bar", t => t.Bar_Id)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.Bar2", t => t.Bar_Id)
    .Index(t => t.AlertCause_Id)
```

then I set a Bar property at Foo as `virtual` and it breaks with "AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException: Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled." And after the migration re-scaffolding the code changes only in that `Bar_Id` becomes `BarId` but for `Bar2` it remains `Bar2_Id`. So I wonder why it gets me the migration re-scaffolded if it seems it does not change anything? Yes it needs the proxy classes and lazy load, etc. but why a new migration?  Thanks!

UPDATE

I've missed that the migration was actually triggered by the adding of a foreign key property, `BarId`. So my mistake here.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason. This is an incorrect question as the migration was triggered because of the adding a reference property (`BarID`). My mistake. So closing it.